# Returning from function argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I'm working with AngularJS a lot right now, but I believe that this is more of a JavaScript question than anything else. Here's snippet from an example controller. Let's assume that it contains an Angular service (defined by me) called 'Restaurants' that I can make queries against.

```
$scope.myFunction = function() {

    Restaurants.query(function(restaurants) {
        // How to return 'restaurants'?
        return restaurants;
    }
}
```

The result of Restaurants.query() is handled by the function argument I gave it. My ultimate goal here is to have the 'restaurants' variable be the return value of 'myFunction()'. But when I return from within the nested callback, it doesn't work.

Two questions:
- Within the callback, where does the return value ('restaurants') go?
- How should I restructure this code so that 'restaurants' can be the return value of 'myFunction()'?

Comment: If `Restaurants.query()` is asynchronous, then you won't be able to `return restaurants`. `$scope.myFunction()` will always exit before `restaurants` has actually become available.   
"[How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)"

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? Do you want to bind against `myFunction` to have access to `restaurants` from inside a template? In this case, you could just define `$scope.restaurants` and then you do `$scope.restaurants = restaurants` inside your function.

Comment: Is `Restaurants` a `$resource` instance ?

Comment: Yes Restaurants is a $resource instance

Comment: I find myself often initializing variables, (for example, available restaurants), using something like data-ng-init="initRestaurants()".

Let's say I want to iterate through a list of restaurants,
it would be great to do this: 

data-ng-repeat="restaurant in getRestaurants()"

Where getRestaurants() is a function that returns restaurants

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning, set a variable on the scope.  Something like this:

```
Restaurants.query(function(restaurants) {
    // How to return 'restaurants'?
    $scope.restaurants = restaurants;
}
```